# Windows 10 System Wide Pauses

Tags: windows-10, debug, event-viewer, pause

I have a rather serious issue on `Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 32-bit`:

[image: Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 32-bit]

On this machine an application is running 24/7 with a lot of networking going on. In total there are 14 network ports.

Rarely (perhaps once a week... but sporadically, yet consistently observed if long enough time passes) we observe some kind of system wide pause, that causes unexpected issues with both network and other internal things going on in the application. An application problem, perhaps, the problem is we are always observing some events in Event Viewer at the **exact same time** this occurs.

Logs from Event Viewer can be seen below. What is going on? How can we avoid this?

First, from `System`. Sorry about the formatting, but hope this can be read.

```
Information     2018-03-11 15:02:59                 Kernel-General                           16                        None 
The access history in hive \??\c:\users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\usrclass.dat was cleared updating 1 keys and creating 1 modified pages.
Information     2018-03-11 15:02:59                 Kernel-General                           16                        None 
The access history in hive \??\c:\users\defaultuser0\ntuser.dat was cleared updating 9 keys and creating 4 modified pages.
Information     2018-03-11 15:02:03                 Kernel-General                           16                        None 
The access history in hive \??\C:\Windows\System32\config\components was cleared updating 1 keys and creating 1 modified pages.
Warning            2018-03-11 15:01:52                 Time-Service   134                      None 
NtpClient was unable to set a manual peer to use as a time source because of DNS resolution error on 'time.windows.com,0x9'. NtpClient will try again in 15 minutes and double the reattempt interval thereafter. The error was: No such host is known. (0x80072AF9)
Information     2018-03-11 15:01:52                 Kernel-General                           16                        None 
The access history in hive \SystemRoot\System32\Config\RegBack\SAM was cleared updating 65 keys and creating 7 modified pages.
Information     2018-03-11 15:01:52                 Kernel-General                           16                        None 
The access history in hive \SystemRoot\System32\Config\RegBack\DEFAULT was cleared updating 229 keys and creating 38 modified pages.
Information     2018-03-11 15:01:52                 Kernel-General                           16                        None 
The access history in hive \SystemRoot\System32\Config\RegBack\SYSTEM was cleared updating 15748 keys and creating 1077 modified pages.
Information     2018-03-11 15:01:51                 Kernel-General                           16                        None 
The access history in hive \SystemRoot\System32\Config\RegBack\SOFTWARE was cleared updating 78112 keys and creating 5756 modified pages.
Warning            2018-03-11 15:01:51                 Time-Service   134                      None 
NtpClient was unable to set a manual peer to use as a time source because of DNS resolution error on 'time.windows.com,0x9'. NtpClient will try again in 15 minutes and double the reattempt interval thereafter. The error was: No such host is known. (0x80072AF9)
Information     2018-03-11 15:01:51                 Time-Service   158                      None 
The time provider 'VMICTimeProvider' has indicated that the current hardware and operating environment is not supported and has stopped. This behavior is expected for VMICTimeProvider on non-HyperV-guest environments. This may be the expected behavior for the current provider in the current operating environment as well.
Information     2018-03-11 15:01:50                 Kernel-General                           16                        None 
The access history in hive \SystemRoot\System32\Config\RegBack\SECURITY was cleared updating 72 keys and creating 4 modified pages.
Warning            2018-03-11 14:59:31                 DNS Client Events                      1014                    (1014) 
Name resolution for the name settings-win.data.microsoft.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.
```

Then, also from `Application`:

```
Information     2018-03-11 15:08:22                 VSS                     8224                    None
The VSS service is shutting down due to idle timeout.
Information     2018-03-11 15:04:51                 VSS                     8224                    None
The VSS service is shutting down due to idle timeout.
Information     2018-03-11 15:03:40                 SecurityCenter                            15                        None
Updated Windows Defender status successfully to SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_ON.
Information     2018-03-11 15:03:40                 SecurityCenter                            15                        None
Updated Windows Defender status successfully to SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_ON.
Information     2018-03-11 15:01:54                 Defrag               258                      None 
The storage optimizer successfully completed defragmentation on System Reserved
Information     2018-03-11 15:01:53                 SecurityCenter                            15                        None
Updated Windows Defender status successfully to SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_ON.
Information     2018-03-11 15:01:53                 SecurityCenter                            15                        None 
Updated Windows Defender status successfully to SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_ON.
```

UPDATE: No Tasks have been run in the last 30 days:

[image]

Comment: It could be Windows 10 maintenance tasks like defrag, disk clean-up, restore points etc. combined with only having 2GB to run in.

Comment: 1 question. why do you sue 32bit Windows if you have 8GB RAM and can't use it? you only have 2 GB usable RAM and here perf issue are expected.

Comment: driver dependencies, not relevant, 32-bit is what it is

Comment: @DavidMarshall how can defrag end up pausing the entire system? restore point shouldn't be happening. But if so, how can I disable all "automatic" tasks?

Comment: with 2GB usable RAM, Windows 10 runs into paging issues. I have the same on my 2GB 8" Tablet running Windows 10. so, you should fix the driver issue and go to 64bit Windows.

Comment: The maintenance tasks are in Task Scheduler. Windows 10 tends to start them all at the same time, especially if there is no idle time. In your events, you can see defrag, VSS is used for Restore points and backup, may be a Defender scan going on and trying to do a settings synchronisation. Dism, which is disk heavy is also run at this time. If you can leave Task Manager running, the Performance tab might give you an idea of where the bottleneck is after you get access back.

Comment: @DavidMarshall I checked task scheduler and no tasks have run in the last 30 days. So how can it be from task scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

The event log says 0x80072AF9 means "No such host is known", so it suggests that the system is failing to do a DNS lookup on the host (`time.windows.com` in this case).

I don't know exactly what can causes this error code, but it probably suggests the system is failing to talk to its designated DNS server.  Which might suggest Internet issues or (if your DNS server is on your LAN) local network issues.

I've come across a problem like this, which caused a server to put itself on an "Unidentified network" instead of a domain one.  I didn't find the cause, but I suspect that it couldn't find the network router at the time it booted.  Disabling/reenabling the network adapter put it back on its rightful network profile.